# Комбинированное подчинение придаточных

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении "В воздухе, **куда ни взглянешь,** кружатся целые облака снежинок, ***так что не разберёшь***, ***идёт ли снег с неба или с земли"*** - Комбинированное подчинение.

Первое - последовательное, второе - параллельное, третье - однородное.

Вопрос: к какому главному слову относится придаточное "так что не разберёшь" и придаточное "идёт ли снег с неба или с земли" ?

> **А может в последние предложении указан последовательный тип подчинения?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главное предложение: В воздухе кружатся целые облака снежинок, к нему относятся два придаточных с последовательной  связью (придаточное следствия и придаточное изъяснительное и одно придаточное уступки с параллельной связью.

Придаточное изъяснительное относится к опорному глаголу "не разберешь", остальные придаточные (следствия и уступки) относятся ко всему главному предложению.

Схема: [... , (куда ни...),...], так что (...не разберешь), (...).

Comment: Придаточное изъяснительное - идёт ли снег с неба или с земли. Придаточное уступки - куда ни взглянешь? Правильно? А почему уступки параллельная связь? Оно ведь относится к одному главному слову, а не к нескольким? Или я путаю?

Comment: Придаточное уступки относится не к одному слову, а ко всему главному предложению.  Главное предложение имеет две параллельные ветви подчинения: а) уступка; б) следствие + изъяснительное.

Comment: А-а, а)уступка;  б) следствие + изъяснительное. –  тоже параллельное подчинение, и то же время следствие + изъяснительное- это последовательное подчинение. Да?

Comment: Я бы так сказала: придаточное уступки  параллельно последовательно подчиненным придаточным следствия и изъяснения.

Comment: Боюсь, Вы меня запутали. Параллельное подчинение может относится только к главному, а не к  придаточным.

Comment: Меня интересует вопрос: на каком основании придаточное уступки можно отнести к параллельной связи? Ведь последовательная связь тоже относится к главному. Если бы здесь было две параллельной связи, сомнений не было бы.

Comment: Я еще раз повторю: Главное предложение имеет две параллельные ветви подчинения: а) уступка; б) следствие + изъяснительное. Для примера: "В воздухе, куда ни взглянешь, кружатся целые облака снежинок, так что ничего не разберёшь. Это чистое параллельное подчинение. А в заданном предложении добавлено еще последовательное подчинение.

Comment: Спасибо большое,Вера!